# Image and name as title

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

I am building a Laravel Nova application and want to show a user with image and name.

```
 /**
 * The single value that should be used to represent the resource when being displayed.
 *
 * @var string
 */
public static $title = 'name';
```

As you can see above, the $title is used to represent the resource, but I want two values, a image (Avatar) and name (Sting).

Is this possible, or is it possible to show an other value like an image, instead of a string?

Answer (score 0):

Use **Avatar** field

> If a resource contains an Avatar field, that field will be displayed next to the resource's title when the resource is displayed in search results

[image]

https://nova.laravel.com/docs/1.0/resources/fields.html#field-types

Comment: This is correct, but not the answer to my question. I want to show change the way a resource is displayed in an index-page, for example within a other resource with a HasOne relationship.

Comment: Text::make('ImageName', function () {
    return '<img src="'.$this->imageUrl.'" /> '.$this->name
})->asHtml()

Comment: This would be possible, but it is not the current resource. I use a `BelongsTo::make` to display a resource in a other resource. But I want the resource to be displayed always everywhere like Image-Name